# Reassigning multiple tasks to a new user

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, tasks

**Scenario is as follows**:

--> A manager in a company was assigned to-do-tasks using SharePoint workflow on a regular basis.

--> Now this manager leaves the company.

--> Now how will we assign all these old tasks which are due for approval to a new user(a new Manger who joined the company in this case).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Note**: Context is SharePoint 2013 online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the list with tasks, click on List>Quick Edit:
[image]

The list will open in spreadsheet mode. You can sort the tasks to choose the ones that are due shortly:
[image]

You can assign a new person to multiple tasks just by dragging the new person's name across the table (Excel-style):
[image]

After you click on 'Stop editing this list' your changes should applied to multiple tasks and saved.

Comment: Once I stop editing the list changes are reflected. But whenever I open the list again these changes aren't reflected back. Along with this, it also throws an exception on approving the task by the new user, "That this task has been locked by a workflow".

Comment: Yes i understood it the constraint is that the same user whose task is pending has to reassign this way to a new user. Thank you very much.